# operating system and time slice

Tags: time, operating-system, computer-science, slice

i just want to know if this statement is true or false: 
**"The operating system can only function if it is the executable that has the time slice."** If true/false, why? Thank you for your help.

Comment: it is "false".  My reasoning is that the OS controls the use of CPU resources to the executables, therefore it dictates when it needs those resources and doesn't require a time slice. But I am not sure if this reasoning is correct. @ergonaut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you question become relevant for single processor with single core machine where only one task at a time can be executed. 
Operating system, is just collection of routines and services to facilitate the user applications. lets say if app1 needs more memory, OS will involve or app needs I/O then OS will involve. When app needs OS intention, there is specific system to tell OS which do you want from OS. which is System calls. When one of Os task will be in execution then no user app will be in execution. when OS will complete its task it will again assign CPU to App. So in this scenario, OS is an event driven: on some specific events control is handed over to OS.

On above rationale, No OS does not need CPU slice for its execution.